# Print a run of unicode characters in order

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to print a run of unicode characters in order, for instance, unicode 0xc9 to 0xe5. The problem is that I can't just iterate through hexadecimal representations of numbers because if I try to write `\xe8` as `'\x'+'e8'`, SyntaxError will be thrown before the recognition of the parts are combined, so I can't write, and thus I can't represent the second part of that expression using an iterating variable. What's a good way to get around this?

Comment: show your code please

Comment: I mean that, for instance, if I try to write a list comprehension `['\x'+n for n in [hex(m)[2:] for m in range(201,230)]]`, there will be a syntax error for trying to parse `\x` before the parts are combined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `unichr` given an integer; and use it like so:

```
print(''.join([unichr(x) for x in range(201,230)]))
```

Comment: or in Python 3, just `chr`